# Loop through different properties of a json using a sequence of numbers

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I have a JSON with different properties called using a sequence of numbers (BOS1, BOS2, BOS3, BOS4, BOS5...). At a certain point of my code, I want to loop through them.

I know this doesn't work, but will give you an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < 14; j++) {
      data[i].BOS+parseInt(j)
   }
 }
```

The code is more complex than that, as you can imagine, but the thing i'm trying to get data[i].BOS1, data[i].BOS2, data[i].BOS3, data[i].BOS4... And I'm not accomplishing to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no point calling `parseInt()` when you've already got a number.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to delete it, I was actually calling j+1 (because I begin at BOS1) and I wanted to simplofy the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `[]` operator:

```
      data[i]['BOS' + j]
```

For that to work (with the rest of your code), the object would have to look like this:

```
var data = [
  {BOS0: "something", BOS1: "something", ... , BOS13: "something},
  {BOS0: "something", BOS1: "something", ... , BOS13: "something},
  ...
];
```

Note that your loop starts at zero, not 1.